# How to permanently remove attached files from OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-onenote

I attached a 3 GB file to OneNote. Then removed it by selecting it and pressing delete. But file size still remained ~3 GB. I emptied the OneNote recycle bin but still the size was same. I attached same file again and then removed it. Strangely this time size became 4 Gb.

Looks like the file is still attached even after removing. How can I permanently remove the attached file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can optimize the OneNote database file which should reduce it's file size:

1. Open the **File** tab
2. Open the **Options** dialog
3. Select the **Save & Backup** entry
4. Execute **Optimize all Files now**

Comment: Thanks. It brought the file size down to few mega bytes.